# sqlite python if already exist?

Tags: python, sql

Hello i'm new to python and sql and I had a question how do I check if a record already exists ?

```
import random
import sqlite3

randomcode = random.randint(100000, 999999)

def datebase():
    db = sqlite3.connect('Filmdatabase.db')
    db.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS randomcode')
    db.execute('CREATE TABLE randomcode(code INT, name TEXT)')
    db.execute('INSERT INTO randomcode (code, name) VALUES (?, ?)', (randomcode, 'Jay'))
    db.commit()
    cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM randomcode ')
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
datebase()
```

He creates a random values but if the random value already exist he needs to run it again. how?

I know that drop if exist and create table should be removed after the first time els you will only make 1 record every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check the existence of the random value by use [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) statement. Also you could separate your init with your insert operation. The following code is a demo, and could achieve inserting n non-duplicated value into db.

```
import random
import sqlite3

def init():
    db = sqlite3.connect('Filmdatabase.db')
    db.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS randomcode')
    db.execute('CREATE TABLE randomcode(code INT, name TEXT)')

def insert_random():
    db = sqlite3.connect('Filmdatabase.db')
    while True:
        randomcode = random.randint(100000, 999999)
         ###Attention the EXISTS statement
        cursor = db.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM randomcode where code=?)', (randomcode,))
        if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 0:
            break
    db.execute('INSERT INTO randomcode (code, name) VALUES (?, ?)', (randomcode, 'Jay'))
    db.commit()

def check():
    db = sqlite3.connect('Filmdatabase.db')
    cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM randomcode')
    for i in cursor:
        print(i)

init()
for i in range(0, 10): #insert as many as you want.
    insert_random()
check()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a truly random value for a `code` i would use the `uuid` module. `import uuid; print uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'random.org').get_hex()`. This number is so large, that as of Oct 2015 there has been no known collisions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).

But lets say you still want to know without a shadow of a doubt.

```
import random
import sqlite3

def randomcode():
    return random.randint(1,3)

def datebase():
    db = sqlite3.connect('Filmdatabase.db')
    db.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS randomcode')
    db.execute('CREATE TABLE randomcode(code INT, name TEXT)')

    create_user(db, 'Jay')
    create_user(db, 'Joe')
    create_user(db, 'Bob')

    cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM randomcode ')
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)

def create_user(db, user):
    while True:
        code = randomcode()
        if db.execute('SELECT count(code) FROM randomcode where code = ?', (code,)).fetchone()[0] ==  0:
            break

    db.execute('INSERT INTO randomcode (code, name) VALUES (?, ?)', (code, user))
    db.commit()
datebase()
```

I really suggest you DO NOT use the `randint()` and use `uuid`.